Sync Specific Folders with Beyond Compare 4
I want to Sync to folders with Beyond Compare 4. I am working on two systems and want to keep my data updated. I do not want to sync all folders from left to right just specific ones. For Examples in Folder-right is only FolderA in Folder-left is FolderA and also FolderB and FolderC. So it looks like this
--Folder-left---FolderA         Folder-right---FolderA
            |---FolderB
            |---FolderC

So in this case it should only sync FolderA (and all subfolder/files)
My Script file looks like this for syncing right to left
load "folder_left" "folder_right"
option confirm:yes-to-all
sync update:right->left
This works. But when i use update:left->right it also copies FolderB and FolderC which I don't want to.
Is there a way to sync Folder-left to right only when the Folder exists on both sides.

Beyond Compare can't limit a sync to folders that exist on both sides. To prevent FolderB and FolderC from syncing, use a filename filter.
Multiple filters are separated with semicolons. The .\ prefix makes a filter match an exact path relative to the base folder. Using the filter -FolderB\ without the prefix will filter a folder named FolderB at any depth in the tree.
option confirm:yes-to-all
filter "-.\FolderB\;-.\FolderC\"
load "folder_left" "folder_right"
sync update:right->left

